# Can webrtc built on OpenTok API work on IE?

Tags: ios, internet-explorer, webrtc, opentok, tokbox

I'm running the [OpenTok demo WebRTC app on Chrome](http://tokbox.com/opentok/webrtc/demo) - and it works great. But if I load the page in IE, it gives me an error message (about page compatibility).
Pretty obvious solution is to use the old (Flash-based) OpenTok library on IE - but do I have to do it "manually"? Is there some sort of an "automatic switching" library that would try to load WebRTC (2.0) TB.min.js, and if it fails fall back to Flash (0.9) version?

Also a related question - will all these versions interoperate? I.e. can Chromes (running 2.0/WebRTC) talk to IE (running 0.9/Flash) and talk to iOS (running native)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have WebRTC capabilities on IE, users could install [Chrome Frame](http://www.google.com/chromeframe) (for IE6+). It is a valid option, but you should know that it is [no longer](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/06/retiring-chrome-frame.html) being actively supported by Google.

As far as I know, there is no automatic switching library. However, on your server, you could look at the HTTP requests and find out the client's browser. From there, you could dynamically load either the WebRTC or Flash library depending on the browser's support for WebRTC. Currently, the OpenTok WebRTC library supports:

- Chrome 23+
- Firefox 22+

Unfortunately, OpenTok does not interoperate between Flash and WebRTC clients. WebRTC clients can operate with other WebRTC clients (mobile, web, etc.), just like Flash can only operate with other Flash clients. For example, an iOS client would have to use the [WebRTC SDK](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-webrtc) and the Chrome/Firefox web app would have to include the WebRTC Javascript library.